# 2D Arrays and C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Do C compilers differ in the way they treat 2D arrays in C (not C++)? I am doing image processing in C, and it seems to me that dealing with 2D arrays is the most intuitive way, as opposed to a 1D array.

I've also developed some algorithms on my Windows machine to process images by denoising or smoothing. The question I have is should I be worried about carrying these algorithms to another C compiler if I am using a 2D array to store images and filters? Will things hit the fan if one uses 2D arrays in C in the long run? 
So the essence of this question is how safe are 2D arrays in C?

Thanks.

Comment: By "2D array" do you mean `int a[N][M]`, or `int *a[N]` or even `int **a`? The term "2D array" is often (over-)used for any one of those, even though it's not really technically correct for any of them (they are rather "array of arrays", "array of pointers" and "pointer to pointer" respectively). Only the first two can generally be accessed using the `a[i][j]` syntax...

Answer (score 0):

C really only has 1-dimensional arrays. A 2D array is simply a 1D array where each element is itself a 1D array. Compilers treat such arrays identically, so you shouldn't have any problems.